# Restore unfinished Audio.Recording from Expo AV

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I am working on functionality where users are recording long audio files. They might pause/resume the recording multiple times during a session.

The API says that we should stop and unload the recording before playing it.

I am worried that they will lose the audio files for good if they kill the app forgetting to finish the recording.

I have the recording URI pointing to a temporary location on the disk, but I can't load it in a Recording or Sound object, unless I am missing something